# Is it possible to use s3 buckets to create and grant admin privileges on different directorys in my ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftp

I have an ec2 instance that I use as sort of a staging environment for small websites and custom Wordpress websites.

What I'm trying to find out is; Can I create a bucket for `/var/www/html/site1` and assign FTP access to Developer X to work on this particular site within this particular bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Directories on your EC2 instance have no relationship with S3.*

If you want to set up permissions for files stored on your EC2 instance, you'll have to do it by making software configuration changes on that instance, just as if it were any other Linux-based server.

*: Assuming you haven't set up something weird like s3fs, which I assume isn't the case here.

Comment: "Assuming you haven't set up something weird like s3fs, which I assume isn't the case here." Correct. I typically do front-end development and this stuff is a bit out of my depth. EC2 is simple enough to me now, but took plenty of messing around for me to understand it first. I'm looking for a relatively simple way to give FTP access to different developers based on which directory they should be working in. I say relatively simple because I'm no system admin. If that just doesn't exist, or my version of simple is _too_ simple, is there documentation you can recommend for me to get started?